# Does Baneful Bunker cause regular Poison or Toxic Poison?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

I've been reading up on some of the new Pokemon and I noticed that [Toxapex](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxapex_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) gets a Protect-like move called [Baneful Bunker](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Baneful_Bunker_(move)):

> Baneful Bunker protects the user from damage. In addition, any opponent making direct contact on that turn is poisoned.

Does Baneful Bunker cause regular poison status, or Toxic Poison status? (The latter having the increased-damage-per-turn effect of course).

Comment: Based only on the wording, I'd say it's normal Poison. Poison Fang lists its effect as "may also leave the target badly poisoned". Pokémon games are surprisingly specific with their descriptions, except when they leave out things entirely. I hesitate to make this an answer as I can't test it myself.

Comment: Yeah that's my problem as well, I'm trying to build up competitive team ideas but I'm not far along in the game to test these yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have the move, I can confirm that Baneful Banker inflicts regular poison, not toxic poison.